# Intellij Play/debug button disappeared

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

My idea headerbars Play/debug/options menu is missing and I haven't found a way to restore it. Does anyone have an idea how to?

[image: intellij headerbar]

Answer (score 1):

Enable View | Appearance | Toolbar:

[image: Toolbar]